# How to edit .STRING files

Tags: windows-7

I'm having trouble finding any results on how to open `.string` files. I get a lot about programming strings and `.strings` files but unfortunately they have nothing to do with what I need.

It's a binary file from what it appears. When I open it in Notepad++ it appears like this:

[image: fancy mumbo jumbo image]

This is how it looks in a HEX-Editor:

[image: opened in HEX-Editor]

Does anyone know how I can edit these files as I have 4 to edit.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the data in there is supposed to be? That information might help in someones attempt to help you.

Comment: @TheUser1024 Didn't think the data would matter... A `.txt` file with passwords is no different to a `.txt` file with contacts. Either way, it's a language file.

Comment: You are right to a degree, but you don't know exactly yet, what the shape of the answer will be. So it might be beneficial to provide more angles to attack the problem. :-) Anyway, it was just a suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried a regular HEX-Editor like http://www.del-net.com/frmDFHEXEditorE.html ?

Comment: @TheUser1024 I've tried Hex Editor Neo and Visual Studio 2012. Both show the correct formatting for a binary at least.

http://i.imgur.com/5QT1tjl.png

Comment: Where did you get these files from? That would help a lot. *Why* do you want to edit them? What do you want to change in them? Consider posting the output of [file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) - it might help identify what it is. Is it a sensitive file? If not, then you can upload it somewhere and let us take a look at it.

Comment: STR does not appear in here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @Bob It's from a Steam game language pack.

Comment: @ta.speot.is The first line says, "This is an incomplete list". I know so many more that aren't in that list.

Comment: @Spedwards Which game? Better yet, can you upload the file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Rename the extension to .plist
2. Use PLEdit.exe to convert the file to text.  One place to obtain PLEdit is http://www.benthicsoftware.com/pledit.html.  I ran the downloaded file through VirusTotal.com and it came back clean, but I would still check it when you download it on your computer to be 100% safe.

Comment: Only displays the first line in text. It only seems to support `.sql` and `.txt` files.

Comment: Changed the extension once again to `.txt` and it displays the exact same thing.

Comment: @Aakash: I suggest you remove or replace that link, most likely it is fishy. ;-) Check here: http://www.benthicsoftware.com/pledit.html

Answer (score -1):

Try Resource Hacker

http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

I haven't used it in a while but it worked well when I did.

As it is no longer developed, the author names two alternatives:

[XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm)

[Resource Editor](http://melander.dk/reseditor/)

Comment: Does not work on `.string` files. "this is not a Win32 executable file."